# Add a folder to a ApplicationDataCompositeValue

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, storage

I'm trying to store a list of folders to be able to reach them afterwards. (I've previously added them to `FutureAccessList`)

```
List<StorageFolder> folders = new List<StorageFolder>();
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
// ...
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue data = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
foreach (var item in folders)
{
    if (item.Path == null || item.Path == "")
        continue;
    data[item.FolderRelativeId] = item.Path; // this is the line where I get the exception
 }
 localSettings.Values["folders"] = data;
```

I don't understand why I keep receiving this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Error trying to write setting in application data composite value
```

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: Show the code where you actually save the values to the settings.

Comment: @I3arnon Done, I do nothing more than that... Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to make it work:

I incremented a variable and made this variable the key of the DataCompositeValue... `item.FolderRelativeId` seemed to have some special/forbidden characters in it.

```
List<StorageFolder> folders = new List<StorageFolder>();
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
// ...
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue data = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
var i = 0;
foreach (var item in folders)
{
    if (item.Path == null || item.Path == "")
        continue;
    data[i.ToString()] = item.Path; // this is the line where I get the exception
    i = i + 1;
}
localSettings.Values["folders"] = data;
```

Answer (score 2):

ApplicationDataCompositeValue not needed.

```
foreach (AccessListEntry entry in StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Entries)
{
    StorageFolder folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(entry.Token);
}
```